# Script does not execute when returning from sleep state

Tags: 18.04, suspend, ubuntu-mate

I have this in /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/ but it does not execute when returning from the sleep state.

```
#!/bin/sh

PATH=/usr/bin/:/usr/share/sounds/

case "$1" in
    resume|thaw)
       amixer -D pulse sset Master 60%
        cvlc --play-and-exit /usr/share/sounds/My_Sounds/Short_doorbell.wav
    ;;
    suspend|hibernate)
       
    ;;
esac

exit 0
```

I use the sleep key on my keyboard. (Half moon)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the `pm-utils` is the right stuff? Ever since 16.10 (I think) it was replaced by `systemd-sleep`, which reads its "hooks" from `/usr/lib/systemd/system-sleep`.

Comment: /usr/lib/systemd/system-sleep does not exist on my system. @RudiC